# AVAudioPlayer getting error?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, avaudioplayer

AVAudioPlayer getting error like this:

`The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1954115647.)`

I download audio mp3 file from some url using `NSURLConnection` and it is `downloading` 100% and save to DB as BLOB.

And then I am trying to play that file from `AVAudioPlayer` like this:

```
AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:&error];
if (player == nil) 
{
    NSLog(@"AudioPlayer did not load properly: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
} 
else
{
    [player play];
}
```

What I am doing wrong in this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901709/iphone-avaudioplayer-unsupported-file-type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try using initializing `AVAudioPlay` with URL and pointing the URL to the blob file ?

```
(id)initWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url error:(NSError **)outError
```

It worked for me with the local URL setting.