# Play Sound of .mov file with AVAudioPlayer

Tags: objective-c, ios, audio, avaudioplayer, mov

I would like to play the sound, and only the sound of a video I have recorded with the ipad camera. The file is a .mov file.

I successfully play the sound of .mp4 files.
I will show you how I do it for mp4 files.

There are 2 members of my player class. audioPlayer a AVAudioPlayer and _urlOfVideoToPlay a NSURL with a local video.

```
NSError *audioError;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:_urlOfVideoToPlay error:&audioError];
bool prep2play = [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];

NSLog(@"%i", prep2play);

if(audioError) {
    NSLog([audioError localizedDescription]);
}
```

The result is:

```
2012-09-21 14:50:23.312 AppName[2201:907] 0
2012-09-21 14:50:23.315 AppName[2201:907] The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1954115647.)
```

First output is 0, that means prep2play is NO (false).
Second output is error.

Do you may have any ideas on that?

Regards

Comment: Check if this helps you.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901709/iphone-avaudioplayer-unsupported-file-type

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I am sorry again, the solution on this link was to use initWithContentsOfURL instead of initWithData (if i understand you right). so i turned it around and used initWithData, because i already use initWithContentOfURL. but this did not work either, also lead in an Received Memory Warning :-(

Comment: Can you log the path of the URL?

Comment: i do that with NSLog([_urlOfVideoToPlay absoluteString]); yes the video that makes the error comes from file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/C7480810-D7D2-479A-9E2E-0BD6C59F54C9/Documents/cameraRoll.mov and a video that works comes from file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/C7480810-D7D2-479A-9E2E-0BD6C59F54C9/Documents/youtube.mp4 :-)

Comment: AVAudioPlayer does not support .MOV files:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761460/supported-audio-file-formats-in-iphone