# AVAudioPlayer.initWithData throwing exception

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, nsdata, nsurl

I am trying to play the audio from remote URL.

```
let audioData = try! Data.init(contentsOf: URL)
do       
 {
      self.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer.init(data: data) //Throwing error sometimes
      self.audioPlayer?.delegate = self
      self.audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()     
      self.audioPlayer?.play()

 }
 catch {
          showErrorMessage("An error occurred while trying to extract audio file")

  }
```

I have a list of audio url on my server. ***for some audio*** I am able to get the `Data` but in the AVAudioPlayer's init method it is throwing the error. I am not able to get the actual cause for this.

I have the option of `AVPlayer` but why this thing is causing the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just directly Play Audio From URL you have as

```
do
{
  try Manager.player = AVAudioPlayer.init(contentsOf: returnPathAtSelectedIndex(fileName: fileName))
  //Set required delegates and Values

  Manager.player?.delegate = self
  Manager.player?.volume = 1.0
  Manager.player?.prepareToPlay()
  Manager.player?.play()
}
catch
{
  print("Error while playing music: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

My Player

```
struct Manager 
{
   ///AVAudio Player
    static var player: AVAudioPlayer?
}
```

My function func `returnPathAtSelectedIndex(fileName:String) -> URL` Returns a `URL`.

**Edit**

As the AVAudioPlayer plays the file saved into the local. You need to save the file to local and than

> AVAudioPlayer.init(contentsOf:localFileUrl)

will help to play the file and won't generate the crash.

Comment: I have to use that audio file later so downloading the audio to `Data` is compulsory.

Comment: You can Manage the download procedure as a Separate Thread, Like BackGround downloading, URL can be used to play file as one thread, and use Data of URL as Separate Thread , So load wont be on one Controller only , Hope you getting my point

Comment: Yes I tried with local audio file URL and It worked with me.

Comment: if this helped you and query is solved you can close this thread by accepting answer

Answer (score 3):

I try it by the code below and its work fine

```
  let audioData = try! Data.init(contentsOf: url)
    do
    {
        let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer.init(data: audioData) //Throwing error sometimes
        audioPlayer.delegate = self as? AVAudioPlayerDelegate
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.play()

    } catch {
        print("An error occurred while trying to extract audio file")
    }
```

Comment: Yes , It works fine with most of the urls but we are using some audio jungle urls which are causing the issue.

Comment: Or If you want to try with this specific url which is causing Issue - https://s3.envato.com/files/142154780/preview.mp3

Answer (score 1):

Please change your code to this, so you can know more what kind of error is happening:

```
let audioData = try! Data.init(contentsOf: URL)
do {
   self.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer.init(data: data) //Throwing error sometimes
   self.audioPlayer?.delegate = self
   self.audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()     
   self.audioPlayer?.play()

}
catch let error {
   print(error.localizedDescription)
   showErrorMessage(error.localizedDescription)

}
```

Comment: Yes, Just did that and got to know the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging the localised description I was getting the error

`The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1954115647.)`

and below link helped me to resolve my issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5252724/5227570

> Instead of initializing the audio player with the NSData object,
>   save the file to the Documents folder, and then initialized the
>   player with the file URL